# Drawing a parabola with Pygame

Tags: python, math, graphics, pygame

I want to draw a parabola in pygame. I have made a pixelarray object and loop through it to determine if a pixel is on the parabola or not. I seem to get an image that has gaps between the points. How do I make it a single continuous line?

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import math

WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 480

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 32)

pxarray = pygame.PixelArray(screen)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for y, py in enumerate(pxarray):
        for x, px in enumerate(py):
            if int(x) == (int(y)*int(y)) - 30*int(y) + 450:
                pxarray[y][x] = 0xFFFFFF

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
color = 255, 0, 0
first = True
prev_x, prev_y = 0, 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for y, py in enumerate(pxarray):
        for x, px in enumerate(py):
            if int(x) == (int(y)*int(y)) - 30*int(y) + 450:
                pxarray[y][x] = 0xFFFFFF

                if first:
                    first = False
                    prev_x, prev_y = x, y
                    continue

                pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (prev_y, prev_x), (y, x))
                prev_x, prev_y = x, y

    first = True
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to draw the parabola as a series of line segments. How many segments you use will determine how smooth it will look, so if you're computing the parabola x = y^2 + 30y + 450, you'd compute the x values for a number of y values and draw lines from (x0,y0) to (x1,y1) and so on.

If you don't have a line drawing primitive, you'll need to implement one using something like [Bresenham's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithmhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).